# Solving a PDE by constrained minimization

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, calculus-of-variations, lagrange-multiplier

Consider the Hénon problem in the ball:

\begin{equation}
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{rcll}
- \Delta u & = & |x|^\alpha u^{p - 1} & \quad \text{ in } B \\
u & > & 0 & \quad \text{ in } B \\
u & = & 0 & \quad \text{ on } \partial B
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
where $2 < p < 2^*$.

My book (*Morse Index of Solutions of Nonlinear Elliptic Equations*, by Damascelli and Pacella) claims that there exists a solution which is the minimizer of
$$
S_\alpha = \inf_{v \in H_0^1(B), v \not\equiv 0} \frac{\int_B |\nabla v|^2 \ \mathrm{d}x}{(\int_B |x|^\alpha v^p \ dx)^{2/p}}. \label{1}\tag{*}
$$

Now, as I understand, we indeed have that there is a solution $u$ that is the minimizer of
$$
J(u) = \inf_{\frac 1 p \int_B |x|^\alpha v^p \, \mathrm{d}x = 1/p} \int_B |\nabla v|^2 \ \mathrm{d}x \label{2}\tag{**}
$$

My question is,

> Why are \eqref{1} and \eqref{2} equivalent?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

David Stolnicki helped me:

Upon setting $a(v) = \frac{1}{(\int |x|^\alpha v^p)^{1/p}}$, we have
$$
\inf_{v \neq 0} \frac{\int |\nabla v|^2}{(\int |x|^\alpha v^p)^{2/p}} = \frac{a^2}{a^2} \inf_{v \neq 0} \frac{\int |\nabla v|^2}{(\int |x|^\alpha v^p)^{2/p}} =  \inf_{\int|x|^\alpha w^p = 1} \int |\nabla w|^2
$$

As $v$ runs through $H_0^1$, $w$ runs through the restriction and we are done.